# Bash Cronjob not executing second command to start new gnu-screen

Tags: bash, cron, gnu-screen

I have a bash script I'm using to quit a current screen program then restart it.

```
#/bin/bash

/usr/bin/screen -XS bot quit;
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S bot luajit /root/bot/Lumble/client.lua
```

I have it set up to be used via cron
`0 11 * * * /root/rebot.sh >> /root/bot/crons.log`

However, every time it gets executed it logs "No screen session found" (error of the first command) then does not execute the second command (which is to restart the program)
Simply executing the script, whether or not there is no other screen session, it will print the error but continue to the second command nonetheless.
What's the program with my cron job or bash script?

Comment: To get stderr, append a space and `2>&1` to your cronjob.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have `set -e` in your environment. That will exit the script after an error.
See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls?highlight=%28set%29#errexit for more information about `set -e`.
You don't want to stop after an error.

Turn off the set -e setting

```
#/bin/bash
set +e 
/usr/bin/screen -XS bot quit
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S bot luajit /root/bot/Lumble/client.lua
```

or reset an error exit to true.

```
#/bin/bash
/usr/bin/screen -XS bot quit || true 
/usr/bin/screen -d -m -S bot luajit /root/bot/Lumble/client.lua
```